# Changing content in a div with JS without destroying its content

Tags: javascript, java, dom, innerhtml

I am using an application where on change in the select box value my javascript function would be called. In the function I have an if/else statement. If the condition validates, it displays me a graph in my `div`, else it displays text in the same `div`.

```
var arrayDataSource = [];
//for example this array has the following [[1,0.2],[2,0],[3,1]
$.each(test, function(index, value) 
{
    //code to load data to that array
});
)
if(arrayDataSource.length > 0) {
    //draw graph
} else {
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "some text";
}
```

When I try to run the else condition my content gets overwritten as I am using an `innerHTML` to display text.

**Do I have any other options to display text with javascript without using `innerHTML`?** I have also seen some `DOM` functions and other relevant posts but nothing worked for me. My `div` properties should remain as they are even after the else condition.

Comment: can you share code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Use insertAdjacentHTML instead of innerHTML as it does not reparse the element it is being used on and thus it does not corrupt the existing elements inside the element.

```
document.getElementById('overAllContainer').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'some text');
```

A better way to do it would be to append a new element with an attribute such as a class or an id to your overAllContainer in order to easily remove it when your selection changes.
You can do it via

```
document.getElementById('overAllContainer').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p class="message">some text</p>');
```

Or via

```
var message = document.createElement('p');
message.setAttribute('class', 'message');
message.innerText = 'some text';
document.getElementById('overAllContainer').appendChild(message);
```

And then when you want to remove the message based on the selection changing,

```
document.querySelector('#overAllContainer .message').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing content in a div with JS without destroying its content you can simply use `+=;` instead of `=` only.

The code will be `document.getElementById('overAllContainer').innerHTML += "some text";`

Comment: I also tried this. as the div content would be different in if and else so just appending wouldnt help.

Comment: The intention is not to append.
For ex: when the if condition is true ---only graph should appear
when else codition is true ---only text should appear
If we use like above it appends text to graph

Answer (score 0):

Use [document.createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode):

```
var text = document.createTextNode("some text");
document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(text);
```

Comment: This is not to append some thing to the div. the div content for if and else conditions should be different.

Comment: @user168983 I really dont understand what you try to achieve here. If you want to append text conditionally then put it in an if-else. In your example you specifically mentioned that innerHTML does not work for you because that overwrites the content. So what is your goal if neither overwriting nor appending is suitable?